# Turning input data into an array on a backbone model?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, backbone.js

Using mongodb, and backbone models I am trying to store an input value as an array inside a model?

So at barebones let's say I have a small little form.

```
<form id="send-message">
  <input name="message" class="message"/>
  <button type="submit" class="send">Send</button>
</form>
```

Then in my backbone code for the view that contains this form, I submit this data. I am using socket.io so I have some code thats like this. I don't think posting the full code for this view is necessary, but I will and hopefully this will prevent confusion.

```
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette'),
    MessagesView = require('./messages'),
    UsersListView = require('./users_list'),
    socket = io.connect();

module.exports = ChatView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: require('../../templates/chat.hbs'),
    events: {
        'submit #send-message': 'sendMessage'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.messagesView = new MessagesView({ collection: window.App.data.messages });
        this.usersListView = new UsersListView({ collection: window.App.data.messages });
        socket.on('new message', function(data) {
            self.createMessage(data);
        });
    },

    onRender: function() {
        this.messagesView.render().$el.appendTo(this.$el.find('.message-content'));
        this.usersListView.render().$el.appendTo(this.$el.find('.users-list'));
    },

    sendMessage: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $message = this.$el.find('input.message');
        socket.emit('send message', $message.val());

        $message.val('');
    },

    createMessage: function(data) { 

        var model = window.App.data.messages.where({username: data.username});

        _.each(model, function(model) {
            var values = {
                message: data.message
            }
            model.save(values);
        });

        window.App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'Add View: Created a new message!');
    }

});
```

So summed up this just submits the input data to the node server then the server emits a response and triggers `createMessage`.

My question is I want to capture all these messages and store them as an array inside the model. So the data structure would look kind of like this.

```
// This represents the ideal structure of the model at barebones   
var user = {
    username: 'Grant',
    message: {message1: "Hey guys", message2: "Michigan State will win the tourney"}
}
```

Lets take a closer look at the `createMessage` method.. You see I save the message like below, but I am unsure how to get the messages already saved on that model then append a new message, thus creating an array. I'll leave it like it is now, but I have tried using a `.push()` function and tried various ways all failing...

```
createMessage: function(data) { 

    var model = window.App.data.messages.where({username: data.username});

    _.each(model, function(model) {
        var values = {
            message: data.message
        }
        model.save(values);
    });

    window.App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'Add View: Created a new message!');
}
```

The data goes to mongodb so I also have a controller that handles and (I THINK) overrides backbone.sync, but the controller is fired by a router when a PUT request is made `app.put('/api/messages/:id', messages.update);` Then the `update` method handles the data, so possibly I could create the array here.

```
update: function(req, res) {
    models.Message.update({ _id: req.params.id }, {message: req.body.message //Somewhere here I could append?}, function(err, message) {
        if (err) {
          res.json({error: 'Update failed.'});
        } else {
          res.json(message);
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit:** So thinking about it, I do want to generate an array of objects.. My biggest problem is figuring out how to append a new object and generate a new key?

For example

```
var user = {
    username: 'Grant',
    message: {message1: "Hey guys"}
}
```

A user submits a new message, how do I create an object with a fresh key, I tried using backbone to get the `length` of the objects, but that got kind of hairy since this is mostly vanilla based now..

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to make is an object, not an array - that's why `.push()` doesn't work.

---

```
function(value) {
    user.message['message' + (Object.keys(user.message).length + 1)] = value;
}
```

This will add a new value to the object, with the key 'message' + amount of *old* 'messages'.

Comment: You're right the point I was making was that I have fiddled with multiple ways.. Earlier I was considering a data structure like this..
`var user = {
    username: 'Grant',
    message: ["Hey guys", Michigan State will win the tourney"]
}`

Comment: basically I am struggling with taking the old messages and appending a new message as an object, but an object needs a key.. So generating the key and building the structure is what I am confused with.. I should have worded the question better but I don't think generation of keys passed my mind until just now.

Comment: So you don't want an array, but an object; are we clear?

Comment: Well the value is obviously generated by the input, the actual message is the value.. the key can be something like message* ex message1, message2.. but the problem is I would have to implement some math (I think) for example count the array of objects like `model.attributes.messages.length` <- not a good one just example, then pass that in as a variable `messages: {message+SOMEVAR: data.message}` Basically I am confused....

Comment: Yeah it would be vanilla and not a part of the wonderful backbone set, but that would be the same for an array.. I figure an object would be better, but I still get confused when trying to create it as an array... I would say an object so later I can add things like the time the message was sent... etc..

Comment: yeah you're right, this looks about right.. Im so used to working with backbone, I don't have much experience working with objects in a vanilla way. Funny I did actually add into an object similar to the above just the other day.. I may have to modify a few things, so Ill brb..

Comment: Okay I get this and got it to work but it overrides the old message.. Maybe I need to adjust my PUT logic..